# Bassoon line in Pink Floyd song

Tags: technique, bassoon

I played bassoon all through high school and was lured away by rock and roll.  Someday I'd like to take it up again and probably will.

My question concerns the bassoon line in the Pink Floyd song, "Is There Anybody Out There?".  When the nylon string guitar starts its arpeggios, there is what I presume to be a bassoon playing a quarter note pattern that starts on an A and shoots up a couple of octaves.  It sound like an embouchure thing, but I'm not even sure if it's an actual bassoon or something else.  Like all other things completely unfair to bassoonists, the internet has been of no help so far!  Hopefully someone here will give a listen.

Thanks,

Trevcda

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Music P&T.

I'm hearing -

[image]

I'm not hearing it shoot up two octaves at all. There are violin harmonics up there but I don't think the bassoon goes so high. Did they re-record it? I'm listening to the 2011 remastered version.

Comment: That's ok for bassoon.  The bassoon solo that opens Stravinsky's 'Rite of Spring' starts on the C above that A, and even goes up to the D.   Every bassoonist considers ability to play it a necessary professional requirement, just as every clarinettist has to manage the opening glissando of 'Rhapsody in Blue'.  (But it's a synth.)

Comment: @Laurence Payne I know. It's fine. But the OP said it shot up TWO octaves. I know the Rite of Spring very well indeed. I know the range of a bassoon and that bassonists need to be able to play it, scary though it is to start the whole kaboodle off. AND I know about the clarinet in Rhapsody in Blue. BUT if it's a synth it's a remarkably good one for its time.

Comment: That’s what I hear but it sounds an octave up, the first note is a 6th above middle C.

Comment: How strange, John. I just can't hear that. I CAN hear it where I said. I've checked. And I can hear other instruments up there - violins and a synth - but not the bassoon. Is it the 2011 re-mastered version you're listening to, btw? I wonder if they got Brian Gulland to play it. We need a record-sleeve!

Comment: @Laurence Payne This was before yer Akais and yer Roland S-750s. I can't think of a synth that was up to it back then. And anyway if it's not a bassoon how come it's in the tenor clef?  ;-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I listened on iTunes, it doesn’t mention if it’s the remastered version but the line starts at 1:26, right? I compared it to an A above middle C on my keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, it DOES sound like tenor clef on the recording, doesn't it?  :-)

Comment: I was listening to the album version.  It does start around 1:26 and is on the 2 and 3 of each measure in the first phrase only.  I believe Old Brix has got the location of what I'm talking about.  I do hear a violin riding the upper note, but I swear that's a bassoon making that jump.  A compressed music source maybe deleting some of that.  In any case, thanks for jumping in and giving it a listen.

Comment: It was good to hear that song.

Comment: There's a very characteristic synth portamento in that sound.  Don't think a bassoon would do that.

Comment: Oh do leave off!